# CE 1.9 - Configurable product "As low as" price wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

I'm using CE 1.9.2.1 and have tested this on a vanilla installation of Magento. This issue only occurs when my products are associated to multiple websites.

I have applied a price adjustment to two of the three associated products. On the front-end category view, the "As low as" price shows twice the intended adjustment (-£3.00, not -£1.50).

[image: Configurable product price adjustment wrong]

**** UPDATE ****

I have checked the `catalog_product_index_price` table of my database and found that the `min_price` value for my configurable product is incorrect, even here.

I dug a little deeper and found `protected function _applyConfigurableOption()` in 
`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php`

Looking at line `221` it shows:

```
$select->columns(array(
    'min_price'   => new Zend_Db_Expr('i.min_price + io.min_price'),
    'max_price'   => new Zend_Db_Expr('i.max_price + io.max_price'),
    'tier_price'  => $write->getCheckSql('i.tier_price IS NOT NULL', 'i.tier_price + io.tier_price', 'NULL'),
    'group_price' => $write->getCheckSql(
        'i.group_price IS NOT NULL',
        'i.group_price + io.group_price', 'NULL'
    ),
));
```

By trial and error, I changed the second line to the following (removed `i.min_price`):

```
    'min_price'   => new Zend_Db_Expr('io.min_price')
```

I then went back into my product and saved it again which forced a reindex of the database. The `catalog_product_index_price` table showed that the `min_price` value was now -3.0000 so this shows the issue is `io.min_price`.

Now I need to know what to do with the `io.min_price` value so that it doesn't create a double discount when saving to the database.

Comment: Having the same problem here, with an older version (CE 1.9.1.0)... The max_price indexed value in catalog_product_index_price appears to be also incorrect. Did you manage to find a solution ? Thanks by advance.

Comment: check link : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176829/as-low-as-price-wrong-on-product-listing-page-after-magento-upgrade

Answer (score 7):

I finally figured out what was wrong in indexer.

You put me on the right way by indicating that the problem was related to multi-websites.

The price variation will be applied as many times there are websites (minus the website code `admin`, which has the `website_code` 0). E.g: if you have two websites (other than `admin`) and set a price variation of 5, then the variation will be 10 instead 5. If you have three websites, then the variation will be 15, etc.

The problem also affect the `max_price` column.

I looked back into older versions of Magento, and I found that the bug was not present in CE 1.8.0.0 (and may be some of other newer versions between 1.8.x and 1.9.x).

So, after making a diff between files, I found some additions, on latest CE version, in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php ; the offending lines are:

```
$this->_addWebsiteJoinToSelect($select, true);
$this->_addProductWebsiteJoinToSelect($select, 'cw.website_id', 'le.entity_id');
```

As you can guess, those lines are doing some joins to `website`/`store_group`/`store` tables, and `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Abstract::_addWebsiteJoinToSelect()` is precisely responsible of the "bug":

```
protected function _addWebsiteJoinToSelect($select, $store = true, $joinCondition = null)
{
    if (!is_null($joinCondition)) {
        $joinCondition = 'cw.website_id = ' . $joinCondition;
    }

    $select->join(
        array('cw' => $this->getTable('core/website')),
        $joinCondition,
        array()
    );

    if ($store) {
        $select->join(
            array('csg' => $this->getTable('core/store_group')),
            'csg.group_id = cw.default_group_id',
            array())
        ->join(
            array('cs' => $this->getTable('core/store')),
            'cs.store_id = csg.default_store_id',
            array());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

If you look at the generated SQL select query at this state, it will look like this:

```
SELECT `l`.`parent_id`, `l`.`product_id`, `i`.`customer_group_id`, `i`.`website_id`
FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` AS `i`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = i.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `a` ON l.parent_id = a.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cp` ON l.product_id = cp.entity_id AND cp.attribute_id = a.attribute_id AND cp.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` AS `apd` ON a.product_super_attribute_id = apd.product_super_attribute_id AND apd.website_id = 0 AND cp.value = apd.value_index
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` AS `apw` ON a.product_super_attribute_id = apw.product_super_attribute_id AND apw.website_id = i.website_id AND cp.value = apw.value_index
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `le` ON le.entity_id = l.product_id
 CROSS JOIN `core_website` AS `cw`
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.group_id = cw.default_group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON cs.store_id = csg.default_store_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = le.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id
WHERE (le.required_options=0)
GROUP BY `l`.`parent_id`,
    `i`.`customer_group_id`,
    `i`.`website_id`,
    `l`.`product_id`
```

Did you see the `CROSS JOIN core_website AS cw` part? It is risky to do that, as a `CROSS JOIN` (which is, in MySQL, a strict alias of `INNER JOIN`) without joining condition will do the join for each line of the joined table. The number of results is mathematically the product of the number of lines from the source table by the number of lines from the target table. E.g: if you had 2 lines in the source table, and 3 lines in the target table, then a `CROSS JOIN` would give you 6 lines (2 x 3).

In our case, it could be okay, as we want a product for all websites and calculate its price for each website. But, that work is in fact already done by `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Default::_prepareFinalPriceData`, which puts a line for each product and website in `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` table and is called just before `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable::_applyConfigurableOption()`.

Here are the facts: if no `$joinCondition` is specified as third parameter of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Abstract::_addWebsiteJoinToSelect()`, it will result in a `CROSS JOIN` without join condition, which is incoherent because we have already a `website_id` in `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` table. Then... Guess the result: your calculated `min_price`/`max_price` is affected by the fact that a same variation will be duplicated as many times there are websites.

To solve the issue, we have to restore coherence between `website_id` column of table `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` and the same one of `core_website` table. In `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable::_applyConfigurableOption()`, specify the join condition in `_addWebsiteJoinToSelect()` method:

```
$this->_addWebsiteJoinToSelect($select, true, 'i.website_id');
```

In SQL, the join will result to:

```
SELECT `l`.`parent_id`, `l`.`product_id`, `i`.`customer_group_id`, `i`.`website_id` 
FROM `catalog_product_index_price_final_idx` AS `i`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_link` AS `l` ON l.parent_id = i.entity_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute` AS `a` ON l.parent_id = a.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `cp` ON l.product_id = cp.entity_id AND cp.attribute_id = a.attribute_id AND cp.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` AS `apd` ON a.product_super_attribute_id = apd.product_super_attribute_id AND apd.website_id = 0 AND cp.value = apd.value_index
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing` AS `apw` ON a.product_super_attribute_id = apw.product_super_attribute_id AND apw.website_id = i.website_id AND cp.value = apw.value_index
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `le` ON le.entity_id = l.product_id
 INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON cw.website_id = i.website_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store_group` AS `csg` ON csg.group_id = cw.default_group_id
 INNER JOIN `core_store` AS `cs` ON cs.store_id = csg.default_store_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `pw` ON pw.product_id = le.entity_id AND pw.website_id = cw.website_id
WHERE (le.required_options=0)
GROUP BY `l`.`parent_id`,
    `i`.`customer_group_id`,
    `i`.`website_id`,
    `l`.`product_id`
```

Ok, our join now looks like this: `INNER JOIN core_website AS cw ON cw.website_id = i.website_id`.

Then... That's it. Problem solved.

Hope it will help some people. And don't expect Magento to correct the problem, as the version 2 is now out and that there will be probably only security updates in the future...

Comment: can you please explain this I am also having same issue but not getting your answer. please help. If you can write the exact code and files where I have to change please do.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a champ. It's amazing after spending hours trying to fix Magneto, it comes down to a 17 character fix in one line of code.  If someone else needs this, copy the core file and apply the patch to here - app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php