# As low as price wrong on Product Listing Page After Magento Upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, price, upgrade

i have upgrade my magento from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.3.2.
i am facing issue with As low as price on Configurable Product Listing Page .

currently price deduct price of custom option 2 times.
[image]

any help appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override Configurable.phtml file from app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php

```
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price/Configurable.php
```

Replace '->columns(array('customer_group_id', 'website_id'), 'i')' with below code. line no : 145

```
->columns(array('customer_group_id', 'website_id'), 'i')
->join(
            array('cw' => $this->getTable('core/website')),
            '',
            array())
        ->join(
             array('le' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')),
             'le.entity_id = l.product_id',
             array())
        ->join(
            array('csg' => $this->getTable('core/store_group')),
           'csg.website_id = i.website_id AND cw.default_group_id = csg.group_id',
           array())
           ->join(
            array('cs' => $this->getTable('core/store')),
            'csg.default_store_id = cs.store_id AND cs.store_id != 0',
            array())
```

Comment below code : line no - 164 to 167

```
//->join(                   
 //               array('le' => $this->getTable('catalog/product')),        
 //               'le.entity_id = l.product_id',        
 //               array())
```

Comment below line : Line no - 170

```
// $this->_addWebsiteJoinToSelect($select, true);
```

Need to reindex Product Prices