# Product list page configurable product price in negative value in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, price

Product list page configurable product price in negative value in Magento 1?

How to correct it?

[image]

Single product page the price is correctly showing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to a core Magento indexer bug that causes the minimum price of a configurable product to be calculated by multiplying the lowest associated simple price by the number of stores the configurable is assigned to.

You would have to override the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price_Configurable` file.

See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176831/72928 and https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/93034/72928